# Define conversion when changing a column type with Sequelize

Tags: type-conversion, migration, sequelize.js

I want to change a column type from BLOB to TEXT, and I think that it would be logical to somehow specify what to do with each field (i.e. create a string with utf8 encoding), but I cannot find anywhere if you can define JS transformations during a migration.

Answer (score 2):

It's not currently possible because the underlying SQL models don't support it. Instead, you could create a placeholder column, copy the values over, delete the old column, then rename the new column.

More info in the sequelize Github thread [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4417). Taking an example from the thread:

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return [
      await queryInterface.addColumn('jobs', 'matterInfo', {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(150),
        defaultValue: ''
      }),
      await queryInterface.sequelize.query(
        'UPDATE jobs SET matterInfo = CONCAT( matterNumber, " / ", matterName);'
      ),

      // remove unused fields
      await queryInterface.removeColumn('jobs', 'matterName'),
      await queryInterface.removeColumn('jobs', 'matterNumber')
    ];
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    /*
      Add reverting commands here.
      Return a promise to correctly handle asynchronicity.

      Example:
      return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
    */
  }
};
```